# CUDA, using memset(or fill or ...) to set an array of float to max val possible

Tags: c++, cuda

Edit: Thanks for the previous answers. but in fact I want to do it in CUDA, and apparently there is no function Fill for CUDA. I have to fill the matrix once for each thread so I want to make sure I'm using the fastest way possible. Is this for loop my best choice?

I want to set the matrix of float to the maximum value possible (in float). What is the correct way of doing this job?

```
float *matrix=new float[N*N];

for (int i=0;i<N*N;i++){
        matrix[i*N+j]=999999;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you're looking for the maximum value representable by a float, you'll want `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` instead of 999999.

Comment: Maybe you've figured this out by now, but if you need to change your question that much, you ought to mark an answer to the original question correct and simply ask a new question.

Comment: I see that, it was a mistake :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` and `std::fill` as:

```
#include <limits>     //for std::numeric_limits<> 
#include <algorithm>  //for std::fill

std::fill(matrix, matrix + N*N, std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
```

Or, `std::fill_n` as (looks better):

```
std::fill_n(matrix, N*N, std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
```

See these online documentation:

- [std::fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/)
- [std::fill_n](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/)

Comment: Because the question is asking about filling in CUDA and C++ standard library solutions are not applicable to CUDA, that is why.....

Comment: @talonmies: The question has been changed after many posted their answer.

Comment: @Nawaz ... don't worry, I'm giving you and everyone else with the original C++ answer a +1 to offset the silly drive-by ... it's not fair to the rest of us ...

Answer (score 20):

The easiest approach in CUDA is to use [thrust::fill](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__filling.html#gac8bd6f546d43f61fcbcacd789103448d).  Thrust is included with CUDA 4.0 and later, or you can [install it](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide#prerequisites) if you are using CUDA 3.2.

```
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
...
thrust::device_vector<float> v(N*N);
thrust::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), std::numeric_limits<float>::max()); // or 999999.f if you prefer
```

You could also write pure CUDA code something like this:

```
template <typename T>
__global__ void initMatrix(T *matrix, int width, int height, T val) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (int i = idx; i < width * height; i += gridDim.x * blockDim.x) {
        matrix[i]=val;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    float *matrix = 0;
    cudaMalloc((void*)&matrix, N*N * sizeof(float));

    int blockSize = 256;
    // ceil division
    int numBlocks = (N*N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    initMatrix<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(matrix, N, N, 
                                         std::numeric_limits<float>::max()); // or 999999.f if you prefer
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer for **CUDA**, which is what the question is actually asking about.

Comment: @talonmies The question has been edited and you are running around downvoting people for a failure by the OP.

Comment: @harrism Question: why does i have to increment by the total amount of threads?

Comment: @user3921720 see [this post](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate through the array and set each `float` element to `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` in `limits` ... you can't use `memset` for this since it sets every **byte** in a memory buffer, not a multi-byte value like a float, etc., to a specific value.

So you would end up with code that looks like the following since you're only using a single array for your matrix (i.e., you don't need the second for-loop):

```
#include <limits>

float* matrix = new float[N*N];

for (int i=0; i < N*N; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
}
```

The second huge problem with your request is that `memset` takes an integral-type for the value to set each byte to, so you'd have to get the actual bit-pattern of the max floating point value, and use that as the input to `memset`.  But even that won't work since `memset` can only set each byte in a memory buffer to a given value, therefore if you pass a 32-bit integral value representing a floating point value to `memset`, it's only going to use the lower 8-bits ... so in the end it's not just something we're not advising you to-do, but it's impossible for the way that `memset` has been implemented.  You simply can't use `memset` to initialize a memory buffer of multi-byte types to a specific value unless you are wanting to zero-out the values, or you are doing some odd hack that lets you write the same value to all the bytes that compose a multi-byte data-type.

Comment: you shouldn't use `FLT_MAX` in C++, use `numeric_limits` instead

Comment: For anyone else who would like to downvote this question because it's not correct for CUDA, please keep in mind this was not originally a CUDA question but a C++ question, and that topic was added after an edit.  That is why you see everyone else has answered for C++, not CUDA.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to easily do this job, use [std::fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) instead which is in **algorithm** header.

```
std::fill( matrix, matrix + (N*N), 999999 ) ;
```

Comment: +1 ... I'm going back and upvoting everyone else here that got the silly downvote for not giving a CUDA answer when the OP left that detail out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using dynamic memory in C++, use `vector` and watch it do all the work for you:

`std::vector<float> matrix(N * N, std::numeric_limits<float>::max());`

In fact you can even make it a 2d matrix easily:

`std::vector<std::vector<float> > matrix(N, std::vector<float>(N, std::numeric_limits<float>::max()));`

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Way:

```
std::fill(matrix, matrix + N*N, std::numeric_limits<float>::max());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `matrix` global memory or thread local memory? If it is in global memory, and you only need to initialize (rather than a reset in the middle of a kernel), then you can use memset from the host before launching the kernel. If it is in the middle of the kernel, consider breaking the kernel into two pieces so you can still use cudaMemset.

```
cudaMemset(matrix,std::numeric_limits<float>::max(),N*N*blockSize);
```

Comment: it's in fact in global memory but as far as I know cuMemset assigns each byte starting from pointer matrix instead of assigning each 8 byte. Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: ah yes. interesting, and no, I don't.